# Rails - Nested Form - whitelisted parameter is unpermitted?

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Tried to deploy to Heroku - Failed! Went back to commit prior to attempting Heroku deployment. Now posting form doesn't work and the log is stating that a parameter which is whitelisted isn't permitted?

Not sure what's happened! Post form was working

http://imgur.com/W6FxL7n

posts_controller.rb

```
 private

 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:tag_list, :id, things_attributes: [:text, :url, :order, :image, :quote, :source, :video, :id])
 end
```

Comment: Issue with validation - solved

Answer (score 0):

You are whitelisting `things_attributes`, but your form is submitting some stuff under `things_attributes` and other stuff under `thing_attributes` (singular not plural). So fix your form so that everything is `things_attributes` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback Paul! I believe it was a separate issue regarding my validations. Apologies